# same program could not fully use CPU resource on another machine

Tags: docker, apache-spark, cpu-usage

I have 2 machines, with same CPU, 4 numa nodes and 24*4 = 96 cores totally, I use spark `local[96]` to run my program, using `htop` to see CPU usage, on the first machine, the 96 cores are almost 100% used

On the second one, I use the exactly same code (spark code packaged in docker image and I use the same image), but `htop` could see all 96 cores only have 25% to 33% CPU usage.

I use `lscpu` to check, except the parameter `CPU MHz`(first one about 3000 and second one is 999.963), the others are all the same(`max MHz 3800, min MHz 1000`, hyper-thread are both disabled).

Why my Spark program could not fully use CPU on the second machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might well be the cooling system's issue, after our confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Check BIOS on the second one. For some reason is not using all CPU speed, perhaps energy saving mode is on or auto.